# Range for multiple cells not working in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to access multiple cells at the same time as follows:

```
Set rng = Worksheets("dts").Range("A3,C3:D3,G8,I8:J8,G9,I9:J9,G21,I21:J21,G30,I30:J30,G39,I39:J39")
```

When I rangetoHTML as follows:

```
rangetoHTML(rng)

Function rangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2013
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    rangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    rangetoHTML = Replace(rangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

It skips the line rng.Copy. Not sure why. Need some guidance on this.

Comment: Excel won't let you copy on "multiple selections" - that's what I'm getting when testing your code

Comment: why is that so?

Comment: Excel is like that. It does the same if you try it in the GUI. Try to make a multiplt selection in the GUI and type `CTRL+C`, you will get the same message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to loop through all range cells to be copied

but `Areas` property of `Range` object could help and  you can also avoid setting a `tempWb` while just create it "on the fly" and dismiss after it's no longer useful

like follows:

```
Function rangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2013
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
    Dim area As Range, cellToOffsetFrom As Range

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    With Workbooks.Add(1) '<--| create temp wb
        With .Sheets(1)
            Set cellToOffsetFrom = rng.Areas(1).Cells(1, 1) '<--| get the 'rng' upleftmost cell as reference for offsetting all other ones
            For Each area In rng.Areas '<--| loop through 'Areas'
                area.Copy '<--| copy single 'Area', i.e. contiguous cells
                With .Cells(area.Cells(1, 1).Row - cellToOffsetFrom.Row + 1, area.Cells(1, 1).Column - cellToOffsetFrom.Column + 1) '<--| reference proper target cell to paste values
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
                End With
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Next
            On Error Resume Next
            .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
            .DrawingObjects.Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With

        With .PublishObjects.Add( _
            SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
            Filename:=TempFile, _
            Sheet:=.Sheets(1).Name, _
            Source:=.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
            HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
            .Publish (True)
        End With
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False '<--|'Close TempWB

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    rangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    rangetoHTML = Replace(rangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Function
```